# Script issue on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I use dynamic options, the second option looks strange when the script is run.

[image]

I've made a fiddle with the problem http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/GqGGA/ but it won't run the script that should activate the dynamic option:

```
function cities(obj){



if(obj.value == '3'){

 //undisplay cities options municipality_control2

document.getElementById('municipality_control').style.display='none'

}else{

$('#cities').load('/cities?regionId='+obj.value);
}
}
```

How can my problem be resolved?

Comment: Proivde an online link where this issue exists.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `document.getElementById` when jQuery is available? That's like picking up your hammer instead of your nailgun, to make a construction analogy.

Comment: The live link where the problem is happening is www.koolbusiness.com and as you can see I couldn't reproduce the problem in the fiddle. I can remove the styling alltogether for the select and then both the styling and the problem will go away but I don't want to lose the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a pseudo css class that jQuery adds a style called active and then forces it to behave.  Because this is the active control it has the active styling.  You can see it in your example if you click on the dropdowns.

If you force remove this styling with code like this http://jsfiddle.net/mGAs4/5/ it will go away.  You can also add CSS to change what the active class does for this type of element.

Something like

```
select:active { background:white; }
```

I think this will also work

```
select.active { background:white; }
```

But I have not played around with jQuery's active support much.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but I can't get it to work. The live link is www.koolbusiness.com and as you see I can't reproduce the problem in the fiddle